# put an if condition check in Powershell

Tags: powershell

below command give me list of Database ID. I would like to check if Database with ID "Demo234" is present or not . if it is present then do not run create command. How can I put a check in PowerShell
"`Get-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext`"
this give me this result

```
Id                   Etag                                 ResourceId Timestamp             Uri
--                   ----                                 ---------- ---------             ---
Recordings           00000000-0000-0000-4635-3ba0a42701d7 bSYMAA==   5/11/2021 9:14:07 AM  dbs/bSYMAA==/
Demo                 00000000-0000-0000-6676-34a9adfc01d7 -c9DAA==   6/21/2021 10:19:50 AM dbs/-c9DAA==/
Recordings1          00000000-0000-0000-4bb8-bf9ee7ec01d7 5IRUAA==   5/18/2021 9:38:09 AM  dbs/5IRUAA==/
NewlyCreatedDatabase 00000000-0000-0000-4533-a3c0202f01d7 HnFmAA==   5/10/2021 2:30:12 AM  dbs/HnFmAA==/
Demo1                00000000-0000-0000-6677-50973abc01d7 kDRqAA==   6/21/2021 10:27:46 AM dbs/kDRqAA==/
Demo2                00000000-0000-0000-6677-776a114801d7 ibV2AA==   6/21/2021 10:28:52 AM dbs/ibV2AA==/
Demo23               00000000-0000-0000-6678-9ce4ecc001d7 vTl6AA==   6/21/2021 10:37:04 AM dbs/vTl6AA==/
```

I have this command to execute which create new database but only after database id is already not there `"New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'demo234'"`

Comment: As `Get-CosmosDbDatabase` returns a `[PSCustomObject]` array, something like `$my_db = Get-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext`, `$my_demo = $my_db | Where-Object -Property Id 'demo234'`, `if (!$my_db) { New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'demo234' }`.

Comment: @Zilog80 - Test your code to verify that it works, and then propose it as an answer. The Stack Exchange model generally discourages Answering a Questions in the comments.

Comment: @Zilog80 please post your comment as answer

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I don't have a Azure cosmo db to test it, that's the reason for suggesting that as a comment.

Comment: @Zilog80 your suggestion worked. you can post it as answer, slight correction Property Id -eq "Demo123"

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Done. Please review the posted code as i can't test it from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZZZSharePoint tested it, a way to check if a cosmo database is present :

```
# Storing databases list as an array of [PSCustomObject]
$my_db = Get-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext
# Search for a specific database in that array by Id
$my_demo = $my_db | Where-Object -Property Id -eq "Demo123"
# Checking if that specific database was found
if (!$my_db) { 
    # The specific database was not found, thus we create it
    New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'Demo123'
}
```

Explanation :

As the `Get-CosmosDbDatabase` function returns a `[PSCustomObject]` array, we can use the PowerShell *cmdlets* dedicated to objects manipulation like `Select-Object`, `Where-Object`, etc.

Thus we use `Where-Object` to locate a specific database by Id in the array and then decide to create this database if it can't be found.